# How to do the testing of viewmodels

Tags: .net, wpf, unit-testing, mvvm, nunit

Can somebody explain me how to do the nUnit testing for WPF viewmodel.
I am new to this. I created a nUnit project however i am not sure how to run this.

Is this through the nUnit exe or directly from Visual studio?

Is there any help avbailable on running the test?

Comment: Writing unit tests for ViewModel objects shouldn't be any different than other objects in your code.  Have you written any nUnit tests for your business model objects?

Answer (score 0):

As explain Andrew, the goal of your viewModel is to be a testable representation of your UI.
Thus testing your viewModel is the same thing than any other objects.

I would recommand you to be more familiar with Nunit:
http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=quickStart&r=2.2.10

Run your tests through VS or the Nunit exe is the same, this is just easier with the VS integration.